# Overlay multiple rectangles on a resized image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, rectangles

I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to visualize images with rectangles drawn over the faces in each image.
I have information about the width, height, top left X and Y co-ordinates (in pixels wrt the original image) of each rectangle in each image.

My C#:

```
public class FaceRectangle
{
    Rectangle rect;        

    public FaceRectangle(int topX, int topY, int width, int height)
    {
        rect = new Rectangle(topX, topY, width, height);
    }
    public int X { get { return rect.X; } }
    public int Y { get { return rect.Y; } }
    public int Width { get { return rect.Width; } }
    public int Height { get { return rect.Height; } }
    ...
 }

public class Photo
{
    public BitmapImage Img { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<FaceRectangle> Faces { get; private set; }
    ...
}

public class PhotoCollection : ObservableCollection<Photo>
{
 ...
}
```

After looking through related questions, this is the XAML I have - but I'm having trouble overlaying the rectangles on the image and adjusting their size and posiiton to match the image. How should I go about achieving this?

**UPDATED XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="TempFaceViewer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:er="clr-namespace:TempFaceViewer"
        xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=System">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ImageListItem">
        <Style.Resources>
            <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Gray" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>

    <!-- Main photo catalog view -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" x:Key="PhotoListBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" >
                    <WrapPanel Margin="5" IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                   ItemHeight="95" 
                   ItemWidth="95" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- Image Template -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type er:Photo}">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="6">
            <!-- Drop Shadow -->
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="4" Background="#44000000">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="5" Y="5" />
                </Border.RenderTransform>
                <Border.BitmapEffect>
                    <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="8" />
                </Border.BitmapEffect>
            </Border>
            <!-- Image Template -->
            <Border Padding="4" Background="White" BorderBrush="#22000000" BorderThickness="1">
                <Image Source="{Binding Img}" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Photos}}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,10" Height="160">

            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ListBox 
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                Name="PhotosListBox" 
                Style="{StaticResource PhotoListBoxStyle}" 
                Margin="5" 
                SelectionMode="Extended" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                SelectedIndex="0" 
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ImageListItem}"                   
                >
                </ListBox>
            </ScrollViewer>

    </DockPanel>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="{Binding Img}" />
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Faces}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="er:FaceRectangle">
                        <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set your canvas top/left properties in ItemContainerStyle instead and put both the background image and the ItemsControl in a Grid so that they're overlapping, aligned and using the same scale (pixels). If you wrap this grid in a ViewBox then everything will scale together as needed:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding Img}" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Faces}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="er:FaceRectangle">
                    <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

UPDATE: You'll have to post any other code on the page. I've tried putting it in a grid as you describe and it works fine, there's nothing else in my window other than this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="{Binding Img}" />
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Faces}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="er:FaceRectangle">
                        <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

I suspect you've got resources elsewhere (i.e. Styles, DataTemplates etc) that are changing the default behavior, trying running my code in an isolated app.

Comment: You should also set `Stretch="None"` on the Image control.

Comment: Honest question: is that actually necessary in this case? Correct me if I'm wrong but wrapping the Grid in the ViewBox should make it size itself to the Image in which case setting Stretch isn't actually required. Always willing to be proven wrong...

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize the Viewbox. But still it would make sense to set Stretch to None, just in case OP wouldn't use a Viewbox, but prefers to display everything in absolute coordinates.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Thanks for the answer! It still doesn't resize or place the rectangles correctly though. I'm putting the Viewbox in an external Grid (layout of the application) so the only modification to your XAML is <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">. But it seems the rectangles are being resized and placed at a different scale - so they end up being too big and offset incorrectly, sometimes bleeding into the adjacent panel.

Comment: @MarkFeldman I've updated the post with the full XAML section - I don't see how the existing styles could affect the final output. The intent is to have something like a filmstrip on the top and the photo at the bottom. Photos is a PhotoCollection. I appreciate your help! The formatting is driving me crazy!

Comment: @Sau Very strange, it's working fine on my build. I currently have 3 theories as to what could be wrong: 1) you're building with an earlier version of WPF (I'm on 4.5), 2) there's something strange about the images you're using, or 3) you're getting aliasing because you're using System.Drawing.Rectangle instead of System.Windows.Rect (the former uses ints, the latter uses doubles). Also your images are stored locally, right? You're not loading them from the web or anything? If you can put together a minimal project and upload it somewhere I'll be happy to have a look at it for you.